# Php change string inside CSV file

Tags: php, csv

I have a bad CSV file where in some point there are strings like `&#039;`

I want to sanitize it because ; is my delimiter.

Is there a php function that can open the CSV file as string so I can replace all '?

Thanks

Comment: Please take a look of your question (at least once) after you have posted it and see whether it displays what you want to convey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the file_get_contents() to read your CSV file as a string, then use the str_replace() function to replace the ' character with the replacement character.

Example

```
$myCsvString = file_get_contents('your_file.csv');
$cleanedCsvString = str_replace('&#039;', "'", $myCsvString);
// save output to new file
file_put_contents("outputCsv.csv",$cleanedCsvString);
```

Hope it helps...